# Mobile compatible ADFS?

Tags: adfs, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm deploying Dynamics CRM 2011 to my organization tomorrow and the only thing left bugging me is the mobile express experience.  When the user enters the mobile URL for the CRM, they're first redirected to the ADFS login page which is not very mobile-friendly.  Is there any way to change this so the mobile friendly CRM url redirects to a mobile friendly ADFS URL?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but hopefully helps someone out there.

You'd need to customise the AD FS pages to get something mobile friendly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx might help. Please note I am no developer but I have seen people customise these pages for mobiles.

You might also be interested to know that the AD FS in Windows Server "8.1" release is customisable and is more mobile friendly too. Check out the demos in the presentation made at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WCA-B334 where the page layout changes to always make the logon fields clearly accessible as the page is resized.